# Is there a way to hover over a link in one class to trigger an animation in another using Tailwind CSS?

Tags: html, tailwind-css

I am having trouble getting a link animation in TailwindCSS (which has made life easier) to work...

What I want to do is hover over `About` and get an animation to work. At the moment, when I hover over the link in a `div`, nothing happens, but when I hover over the clearspace/ &nbsp (which is also inside the `div`), the animation plays.

Here's some code:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com?plugins=forms,typography,aspect-ratio,line-clamp"></script>

<div class="group text-black text-xs text-center relative">  
  <a href="#">
   <span>
     About
   </span>
   <span class="absolute -z-10 top-0 -right-4 group-hover:transition-all duration-300 ease-in-out group-hover:border-r-8 group-hover:border-red-700">
     &nbsp;
   </span>   
 </a>
</div>
```

Any help greatly appreciated...

P.S. Also the whole `div` moves to the left when hovered over (including the `About`). This shouldn't happen...

Comment: apply hover on button, it will work as you need. currently hover is applied on span

Comment: That didn't work :( Would it have anything to do with z-index?

Comment: Update the code with hover on the button in question and let me see

Comment: Can't... code snippet doesn't support Tailwind CSS

Comment: Do not add `(Got it working)` to the title, accepting an answer already marks a question as being solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply tailwind classes on the html and it will work fine. Try that:-

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com?plugins=forms,typography,aspect-ratio,line-clamp"></script>

     <div class="button group text-black text-xs text-center">
        <a href="#">
           About
              <span class="link transition-all duration-300 ease-in-out group-hover:border-r-4">
                  &nbsp;
              </span>
        </a>
      </div>
```

Comment: It almost works...However the "About" link is also moving from original point to 4 pixels to the left (when hovered over)

Comment: @Transformers You can go to console and and select hover over the button. You will see that only span with class link is taking border animation. And the About text is moving because the width increase so, it normally just move to back. Its not because of hover. You can check hover only effecting the span with link

Comment: Knew z-index played a part...got it working now thanks! (see original post for updated code)

Comment: @Transformers Yeah that's why I was saying It was working. Good the problem is fixed

Comment: @Transformers If its helpful, mark the answer correct for future visitors.